# Why can we shake/wipe away static electricity?

Tags: electrostatics, electricity, electrons, water, molecular-dynamics

If I take a blanket out of the dryer and it's stuck together with a lot of static build-up, I am able to pull it apart and simply shake it out for a few seconds and all the static electricity will be gone.

Or if I take off my sweater and it builds up some static in the process.  I can just "wipe" it off for a few seconds and it's gone.

How can I do this without the electricity (seemingly) discharging anywhere?

Answer (score 5):

Static electricity is counter-intuitive, because small charges can lead to high voltages. Once you create a path for the charge to move away, that small charge only produces a small current. And because of the high voltage, it's fairly easy to create such a path.

Of course, when the blanket is stuck together because of static electricity, it means there are positive *and* negative static charges, else they wouldn't attract each other and not stick together. So your answer, "where do these charges go", is simply "to each other". The two can cancel, if there's a path between them, and your hand can form that path. That's how you wipe the charges off.

Answer (score 3):

The electron indeed can be affected by forces other than the electromagnetic charge; the classic [Millikan Oil Drop experiment](http://www.kcvs.ca/site/projects/physics_files/millikan/lessons/lessonfull.html) perhaps best illustrates this fact, and was used to determine the size of the charge of the electron.

But in the situation of a sizable material object with charge imbalance (surplus or deficit of electrons), conceiving any means of mechanically removing or adding electrons to balance charge (for example using centrifugal force) would be a very difficult and impractical if not impossible endeavor since the electromagnetic force is so incredibly stronger than gravitational or inertially conceived forces (those that may act on the electron's mass).

Shaking, spinning, etc. is just more likely to provide a conductive path to ground for equalization.

Answer (score 2):

Inside the dryer the moisture is near 0. The lower the moisture in the air the more static charge you get from movement. After the dryer stops the clothes retain some of that charge even after it is removed. The outside environment of the dryer is  normally higher in moisture and neutral in electrons. Water molecules in the air attract electrons and pull the excess electron away from the clothes jumping water molecule to water molecule allowing the clothes discharge into the air. This happens more with movement.

http://www.wikihow.com/Remove-Static-Electricity

[image]

[image]